# Update model within collection where model attribute is x

Tags: backbone.js

Within backbone I have a collection. Where I want to update a model or models within it if a model has a particular attribute value.

I know I can do something to the extent of

```
var model = myCollection.where({some_attr:'something'});
```

where `model` becomes the child object from the collection. However beyond that I seem to get lost. As none of the backbone functions seem to work on it. Example, I can't:

```
model.set({other_attr: 'changed value'});
model.save();
```

I just get an Uncaught TypeError. `model.set is not a function`

again.. Example sake.

So overall I want to find the model, update it, and then save it and its changes to the server? Idea's? Assume I have no workable ID to make getting and setting a little easier, hence why I need to do a where and update like that.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `where` and always working with the array of models it passes.  When you're done updating the models you can make a `sync` call on the collection to bulk update those changes back to the server.

```
myCollection.
  where({some_attr:'something'}).
  map(function(model) {
    model.set({other_attr: 'changed value'});
  });
myCollection.sync('update');
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
var model = myCollection.where({some_attr:'something'});
```

returns an array of models, not a single model. Assuming only one model will match your criteria, you could use

```
var model = myCollection.findWhere({some_attr:'something'});
```

If your collection could have multiple matching models, then you'll want to stick with `.where` but iterate over the array.